# Iterating through a cJSON Array alternatively

Tags: arrays, c, json, cjson

This is the code I am using

```
cJSON *IDs = cJSON_GetObjectItem(tree, "fruitIds");
cJSON *mangoe;

cJSON_ArrayForEach(mangoe, IDs) 
 {

}
```

My JSON object looks something like this
`static char *buffer = "taskData\":[{\"treeId\":123456,\"fruitIds\":[11111,00,22222,00,33333,00,44444,00,55555,00,66666,00,77777,00,88888,00,99999,00],\"numberOfFruits\":9};`

What I want to do is iterate through my JSON array alternatively. For example, first see if I have `1111` in storage, check if I have `2222` likewise and update the `00` variable infront of each value that I compared with `11` if I have that variable in storage.

To accomplish that I need to know the following,

1. Is there a way to traverse the array in multiples of two. (If not what is the best way to do this in a similar manner") Note:- The values I need to compare are at even indices of the array
2. While traversing the array how can I update a position of the array infront of the current index.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the above question

It appears that using `cJSON_ArrayForEach` we can't run the forloop at alternative indices. Instead I used something like this,

To check the index infront of current index

`mangoe->next->valueint`

To update the value of the next index

`cJSON_SetIntValue(mangoe->next, 11);`